# Integration of Kong Ingress Controller 3.0.x with Istio Service Mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kong, servicemesh, kong-ingress

I have been trying to integrate the latest version of Kong Ingress Controller with Istio Service Mesh by following this guide (https://tech.aufomm.com/how-to-use-istio-with-kong-ingress-controller/#Install-Kong) but to no avail.

I have installed Istio and Kong ingress controller 3.0.x (including JWT plugin) and attach the Istio label to the namespaces. Below is the result of doing a curl to one of the ingress path and Kong server is the only one that can be reached unlike the guide where it reached Istio server.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2024 08:09:01 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 26
X-Kong-Response-Latency: 1
Server: kong/3.5.0
X-Kong-Request-Id: 8d4510684dea8d3b7c1cd67126b0a454

{"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Below is the result within Kiali.
[error image from kiali](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0kDA.png)

Please help me verify the above guide that I followed and tell me what to do next.

Comment: I tried that guide before without any problem, could you point to which part of the guide you encountered the error?

Comment: the problem is as I mentioned before, where kong ingress controller is not able to integrate or use the istio server. Supposedly, according to the guide, if I successfully integrate kong and istio mesh i got this result: https://tech.aufomm.com/how-to-use-istio-with-kong-ingress-controller/#Use-Istio-features.